# How many indexes are actually created?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In a Neo4j graph, how many indexes are created into the database if I the same property key is used for nodes labelled differently?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Movie(Name)
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(Name)
```

Does this really create two indexes?
In a huge graph with over 1M nodes, would it be preferable to use different property keys for these two node types?

Comment: Also keep in mind that to use index lookups in the query, you must explicitly have the label associated with that index present in the query.

Comment: Yes thanks. Actually I asked the question because I had the feeling that some indexes didn’t work as well as others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `CREATE`s statements in your question are creating two different indexes. The docs about indexes says:

> An index on a **single property for all nodes that have a particular
>   label** can be created with `CREATE INDEX ON :Label(property)`.

You can list all indexes in your neo4j database running the command `:schema` in your Neo4j Browser.

The output will be something like:

```
Indexes
   ON :Movie(Name) ONLINE 
   ON :Person(Name) ONLINE
```